# How to fix segmentation fault in this program

Tags: c++

Im solving this question but cannot get correct output it show segmentation fault
 https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/breadth-first-search/practice-problems/algorithm/agitated-chandan/description/

This is the code that i write for this program

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int visited[100001], dist[100001];
    int largest;

    int t, x, y, w, i, z, k;
    int large;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)

    {
        int large = 0;
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector<pair<int, int>> adj[n];

        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> x >> y >> w;
            adj[x].push_back(make_pair(y, w));
            adj[y].push_back(make_pair(x, w));
        }
        queue<int> q;
        for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        {
            q.push(k);
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                visited[i] = -1;
                dist[i] = 0;
            }
            largest = 0;
            while (!q.empty())
            {

                z = q.front();
                visited[z] = 1;
                q.pop();

                for (i = 0; i < adj[z].size(); i++)
                {

                    if (visited[adj[z][i].first] == -1)
                    {
                        dist[adj[z][i].first] = dist[z] + adj[z][i].second;

                        if (largest < dist[adj[z][i].first])
                        {
                            largest = dist[adj[z][i].first];
                        }
                        q.push(adj[z][i].first);
                        visited[adj[z][i].first] = 1;
                    }
                }

            }

            if (large < largest)
            {
                large = largest;
            }
        }
        if (large < 100)
        {
            cout << 0 << " ";

        }
        if (large > 100 && large < 1000)
        {
            cout << 100 << " ";

        }
        if (large > 1000 && large < 10000)
        {
            cout << 1000 << " ";

        }
        if (large > 10000)
        {
            cout << 10000 << " ";

        }
        cout << large;
    }
}
```

I expect output be
0 8
Just heck the logic is it write or wrong

Comment: When you debug your code, the error is on which line?

Comment: Honestly, your code is barely readable. 
Fix your indentation and give the variables better names.
Apart from this, run your program through a debugger.

Comment: Actually i dont debug it

Comment: You cannot allocate such large arrays on the stack. Allocate them on the heap (with `new` or a `std::vector`) or as a global.

Comment: _Actually i dont debug it_ That's the point - you should! ;-)

Comment: probably not the problem, but `vector<pair<int,int>> adj[n];` is questionable in several ways. Why create a c-array of vectors? And you are using a VLA here, which is not standard c++

Comment: Now that it is formatted, what are you solving? the link does not work

Comment: Never ever, ever do this: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible cause is that you store indexes from `1` to `n` to the queue `q`:

```
for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
   q.push(k);
```

and then use them (as `z`) for indexing `adj` of size `n`:

```
   while (!q.empty()) {
     z = q.front();  // z equals n in the first iteration here
     ...
     for (i = 0; i < adj[z].size(); i++) // adj[n] will be accessed
```

Indexes in C++ are **zero-based**, therefore the valid ones are from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: There is even a name for such mistakes: [Off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) (and a Wikipedia article in various languages).

Comment: @Scheff Nice, didn't know that.